# Kentico 9 BizForm validation/visiblity rules

Tags: kentico

I'm building out a custom page type. I have two fields, Name and File,  and i'm hoping to accomplish the following:

- File is not visible or active until Name is filled out.
- If Name has a value, then File is required.

I don't see an option to make a field required if another field has a value.

Answer (score 2):

To make the `File` field appear when the `Name` field is set:

- On `Name`  field, check *has depending fields*.
- On the `File` field

  - check *depends on another field*.
  - set *visibility condition*, to `Name.Value != ""`

You can't check required on `File`, but you can set a validation rule that checks if it is null, that validation only runs if the field is visible.

See [Field editor reference](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/developing-form-controls/reference-field-editor) scroll down to *Field advanced settings* for more details on the Visibility condition.